# C# - How can I search in a IQueryable object with Where Like %

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, iqueryable

I don't find a way to make a search on `IQueryable` object with `LIKE %some%text%` operator like in SQL command.

At the moment I do this:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Shop> database_Shops = database.Shops;
string searched_shop = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(post_data["shop"]) ? post_data["shop"] : " ";

ViewBag.shops = database_Shops
                .Where(shop => shop.Name.ToUpper().Contains( searched_shop.ToUpper()))
                .Take(RESULTS_PER_PAGES * pageNumber);
```

But it don't find an entry without space in `shop.Name`. Anyone know a way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Space IN the name is also not found by LIKE, you know.

Comment: yes of course but with `Like` method I can do search all entries WITH& WITHOUT space like this `shop.Name LIKE "%%"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `SqlMethod` in the namespace `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient` :

```
database_Shops.Where(shop => SqlMethods.Like(shop.Name, "%some%text%"));
```

[SqlMethods.Like Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235(v=vs.110).aspx)

In EF Context you can use `SqlFunctions` in the namespace `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions`

```
database_Shops.Where(shop => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%some%text%", shop.Name) > 0);
```

[SqlFunctions.PatIndex Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.patindex(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: "This method is currently only supported in LINQ to SQL queries."

Comment: For me it don't work. I have this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)` .. have an idea?

Comment: Can you paste your full request in your question ?

Comment: With EF you should use `SqlFunctions.PatIndex` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.patindex(v=vs.113).aspx I ll update my answer.